# Is there a way in Pandas to apply .rename() to a filtered subset of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df`, with a standard wide format:

```
df: 
     'state' | 'population' | 'region'
0    'CA'    | 10000        | 'west' 
1    'UT'    | 6000         | 'west'
2    'NY'    | 8500         | 'east'
```

I need to be able to rename certain values in the `state` column that match some conditions I've set. For example, I need to rename cases of 'NY' to 'New York' if the region variable matches 'east'. I'd like to avoid slicing and concatenating the dataframe back together.

I've tried subsetting the dataframe using the code below, but the rename doesn't seem to apply properly.

```
 region_filter = df['region'] == 'east'
 df[region_filter] = df.loc[region_filter, 'state'].rename({'NY': 'New York'})
```

Comment: `rename` changes names of `columns/axis`. Do you want it or do you want `replace`?

Comment: I had swapped the two in my head and didn't remember that rename was for columns/axes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rename should only be applied when trying to change axes labels. Pandas' [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function is meant for mapping dataframe values.

Also, line two should read `df.loc[region_filter, 'state'] = df.loc[region_filter, 'state'].rename({'NY': 'New York'})` to avoid a shape mismatch error.